# lambda running twice, and Runtime exited without providing a reason

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, error-handling, runtime-error

I got a lambda written in Go running on a container, the image was built with alpine-golang and run with alpine.

When testing i noticed from the logs the lambda is ran twice before exiting with the following:

```
Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason Runtime.ExitError
```

From my local system this the code runs fine without errors, i earlier tried running without a container but still faced runtime issues. The only error handling and logging mechs in my code is `log.Println` and `fmt.Printf`. Anyone got an idea of what is going on?

EDIT:

I trapped the exit code, which is turns out to be `0` but lambda exits with

```
 Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: can you post the code you use in the Dockerfile? Lambda is very specific with how it wants to handle running docker images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really suggest going for the "without container" path. Just pack your executable into a .zip archive. Don't forget to compile with `GOOS=linux` for your code to be compatible with AWS Lambda.

On Linux you can use the following commands to get your archive:

```bash
GOOS=linux go build -o executableName path/to/main.go
zip archive.zip executableName
```

Note that you have to set `Handler` to be `executableName` in function's Runtime settings.

For handling lambda function, you have to use `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda` package and in main start the handler function like `lambda.Start(handler)`.

Full code example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}

func handler(ctx context.Context) {
    log.Println("successfully executed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are following the recommended guide lines aws provide with building the container image. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html

your Dockerfile should look like this to work with lambda,

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2 as build
# install compiler
RUN yum install -y golang
RUN go env -w GOPROXY=direct
# cache dependencies
ADD go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
# build
ADD . .
RUN go build -o /main
# copy artifacts to a clean image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2
COPY --from=build /main /main
ENTRYPOINT [ "/main" ]
```

Lambda is very strange where if you have the Dockerfile like you would on a local machine then it runs it once, ends, then a second time and crashes with no reason given

Comment: Used the al2 image, same error.

Comment: can you post your docker and lambda code? Would be easier to understand :)